# How to differentiate between 0 and an empty variable?

Tags: php, variables

Lets say I have a variable $a that holds an integer between 0 to 10. $a needs to be not empty/not null to run a code. It works when the integer is between 1 to 10, but when it is 0, it treats $a as empty.

```
$a = 5;

if (!empty($a))
{ echo "not empty"; }
else
{ echo "empty";}
```

This this case it echoes "not empty".

```
$a = 0;

if (!empty($a))
{ echo "not empty"; }
else
{ echo "empty";}
```

But in this case it echoes "empty".

Is there a way to differentiate between 0 and an empty variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the strict equality operator `===` to test for zero:

```
$a = 0;
$isZero = $a === 0; // $isZero is true
```

Answer (score 2):

check for null an a string length of 0

```
if(null === $a || strlen($) === 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `empty` you could use `isset`: https://www.php.net/isset

```
if (isset($a))
{ echo "not empty"; }
else
{ echo "empty";}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between EMPTY and NULL. For `$a = 0`, `$a` is EMPTY but not NULL. So you can use `isset($a)` to check if `$a` is NULL or not.

```
if (isset($a)) {
echo 'not null';
} else {
echo 'is null'; 
}
```